# ArgumentException for a Combination of Arguments

Tags: c#, exception, validation

I have a method that takes three parameters (3D points). I want to throw an exception if the points are colinear. The obvious exception to me is `ArgumentException`, but the best practise with this is to include the param name in the constructor. In my case it's the combination of all three params which is the invalid input - so the best practise isn't going to work (and I think my code analysis will moan like hell).

So do I use `ArgumentException` here or something like `InvalidOperationException` because there's more than one parameter causing the problem?

Comment: IOE deserves *heavy* consideration.  The client code is asking it to perform an operation that isn't valid.  Unambiguously too, I'd assume.

Comment: [per MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception.aspx), "InvalidOperationException is used in cases when the failure to invoke a method is caused by reasons other than invalid arguments"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think both are fine.

If you choose to use `ArgumentException`, you can use the name of any one parameter. Personally I would use the name of the *last* parameter. After all, if the points are collinear, you need to change only one and then all the parameters are fine. :-)

Comment: I did wrote an helper for checking and reporting even complex rules without having to writ eparameters names as string:http://www.felicepollano.com/2011/12/17/ASingleFileArgumentVerificationLibrary.aspx

Comment: The constructor has an overload that accepts just a message and no parameter name. It's probably meant for the case when there is no specific argument that's causing the problem more than any other (i.e. when it's a bad combination).

Answer (score 3):

Try creating your own Exception type, deriving from `ArgumentException`. In that class you can store all three parameters.